# Phonegap default theme does not show ListView with arrow sign

Tags: android, css, html, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I have created the project having Listview with default theme. My configuration goes as explained below.

1. **index.html** file where all the imports to css, js files are done including cordova-2.0.0.js and other stuffs that are needed. **Index.html** file contains my Login Page.
2. Now, After login I go to home.html page where i have list view configured as below :

   ```
   <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
       <h1>Home Screen</h1>
   </div>

   <div data-role="content">    
     <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c">
       <li><a href="profile.html"><img src="images/profile.png" alt="Profile">My Profile</a></li>
       <li><a href="courses.html"><img src="images/courses.jpg" width="189" height="189" alt="Courses">My Courses</a></li>
       <li><a href="contactsList.html"><img src="images/contact.jpg" width="160" height="160" alt="Contacts">My Contacts</a></li>
       <li><a href="mapPage.html"><img src="images/map.png" width="215" height="215" alt="Map">My Map</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>

   <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
       <h4>&copy; 2012.</h4>
   </div>
   ```

Note that I have not included the header file here. and only this much code is there in home.html file. **(Note here since it is HTML i am not able show my Parent div tag where i have configured data-role="page")**

3. Now, all the themes are getting applied only the arrow is not coming instead a Gray Spot is coming as in below Pic.

[image]

Can any one explain why it goes like this?? I have checked the other project and I have all the imports as it is.

Below is my index.html imports :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- <script src="js/jquery-mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

my CSS **custom.css** goes as below

```
/* CSS Document */

#container0 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div0 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#div1 {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*#footer {
    margin-top:'10px';
}*/

button {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height:2em;
}

.loginBtn {
    width:100%;
}

.info {
    border:1px solid black;
    background:#eeeeff;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
}


/* Map CSS Start */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map_canvas {
    width:520px;
  height: 900px;
}

/*@media print {*/
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  html, body {
    height: auto;
  }

  #map_canvas {
    width: 950px;
    height: 480px;
  }
}
/* Map CSS End */

.ui-content h2 {
    text-align:left;
    padding:0px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.ui-content h4 {
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: that might causing from css conflict somewhere, so its hard to identify without seeing at css classes which you are using with `custom.css` and `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css`.

Comment: @PratikSharma: I have added my custom.css code. And I have not made any changes in  jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css file which i downloaded from internet.

Comment: check the solution I have posted below. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
```

**EDIT :**

I got it solved for local `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css` file.

First copy this image from this link [Arrow Icon](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/images/icons-18-white.png)

You will get image named `icons-18-white.png`.

Save this image into `www/images/icons-18-white.png` path.

That's it.

It works for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem when i refer to website links.... But When i keep same files in local then it does not work. I narrow down the issue and found that only the **CSS** i.e. "jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" file is having issue. I copied that file as it is in filesystem then the Arrow image is not coming.... Can you explain why such weird behavior??

Comment: @MacMini-iOS check the edited solution for your problem. That will work also when you worked by using local `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css` file too.

Answer (score 0):

Use above jquery files on proper places and try this after anchor tag

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: I have that query only... which jquery file will come where??? I tried all possible combinations... Also i tried above code... but that distorts my UI and extra space comes below my images... Please read my comment in other answer... I narrow down my issue..